# How do you pull weekly/monthly historical data from yahoo finance?

Tags: python-3.x, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

By default, this code obtains all the closing days data or several Tickers:

```
tickers = ['SPY', 'QQQ', 'GLD ', 'EEM', 'IEMG', 'VTI', 'HYG', 'SJNK', 'USO']
ind_data = pd.DataFrame()

for t in tickers:
    ind_data[t] = wb.DataReader(t,data_source='yahoo', start='2015-1-1')['Adj Close']

ind_data.to_excel('C:/Users/micka/Desktop/ETF.xlsx')
```

How do you add a parameter to Datareader in order to obtain weekly/monthly historical data instead? I tried using freq and interval but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

What if you try to replace this in your code for weakly data:

```
# Don't forget to import pandas_datareader exactly in this way
import pandas_datareader

# Then replace this in for loop
pandas_datareader.yahoo.daily.YahooDailyReader(t, interval='w' , start='2015-1-1').read()['Adj Close']
```

And this for monthly data:

```
# Don't forget to import pandas_datareader exactly in this way
import pandas_datareader

# Then replace this in for loop
pandas_datareader.yahoo.daily.YahooDailyReader(t, interval='m' , start='2015-1-1').read()['Adj Close']
```

Check [official doc](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readers/yahoo.html?highlight=interval#module-pandas_datareader.yahoo.daily) for further options. After executing this code for the weakly period:

```
import pandas_datareader
tickers = ['SPY', 'QQQ', 'GLD ', 'EEM', 'IEMG', 'VTI', 'HYG', 'SJNK', 'USO']
ind_data = pd.DataFrame()

for t in tickers:
    ind_data[t] = pandas_datareader.yahoo.daily.YahooDailyReader(t, interval='w' , start='2015-1-1').read()['Adj Close']

ind_data
```

I got this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! With this code I get this error: DataReader() got multiple values for argument 'data_source'

Comment: @MickaëlBertolla You're welcome. Answer edited.